# Is it possible to append the data to hdfs using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am having one tab delimited file in hdfs. I need to append the user input to that delimited file in hdfs using Java. I don't know how to implement this. If any one tell me the logic it will be very useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

The class `org.apache.hadoop.dfs.DistributedFileSystem`  has a method `append` which returns a stream object `FSDataOutputStream` in which you can write with `out.write`. This will make your job done. Refer for doc here http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/2/hadoop-0.18.3+76.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/dfs/DistributedFileSystem.html#append%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20int,%20org.apache.hadoop.util.Progressable%29

Answer (score 1):

Please add below property in `hdfs-site.xml` and try

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.support.append</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>
    Does HDFS allow appends to files?
  </description>
</property>
```

Regards,
mar